# How to monitor the command prompt and send an alert in windows if it is closed

Tags: java, windows

I am running an Java program from Command prompt/ with below command.

c:/users/java test and program is running. now i need to monitor whether the command prompt is running or not. if not need to get alert so that i can start the program again. Is there any way to monitor the process.

Comment: not that I know of, since the command prompt is not part of the JVM

Answer (score 0):

Unluckily you cannot directly monitor a command prompt execution via JVM... BUT, you can always redirect the cmd output to a file, read it from your application and acting accordingly.